# How to detect in which line the cursor is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, this might get pretty damn complicated, maybe almost impossible, but maybe someone of you knows the way:

Im currently writing an editor for a self-created, plainsimple language (5 keywords, WUHA!) which works pretty well already. But that's not the point here, now I want to create an editor for it with syntax highlighting. Yes, I want it online if possible, so my only chance is JavaScript/jQuery.

I dont have much code yet, this is all I got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Kevcode Editor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var keywords = ["KEYWORD2", "KEYWORD3", "KEYWORD4"];

        $("#editor").keydown(function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 13) {
               //GET THE LINE HERE
               //mark keywords here
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: grey;">
<label for="editor"><textarea id="editor" style="width: 1200px; height: 800px;"></textarea></label>
</body>
</html>
```

So my plan was to create a `textarea` and if I press Enter (which is represented by the keycode 13), ill run a script which checks every line and recolors the keywords. But then I thought that it would be a huge waste of resources to check the whole script. Of course the scripts wont be too long with 5 keywords, but if I add more and more, it would be horrible to check the whole code. So i thought that just checking the current line where I changed something would save me a lot of time. But how can I implement such a logic? How can I tell jQuery in which line the cursor currently is?

Sorry if I explained something unclear, if you got any questions please ask and I will give as much information as possible.

Oh, and don't give me finished solutions please. Ill do this for training purposes.

Comment: You won't be able to change the color on a line-by-line basis. Most syntax highlighting tools use a fake `textarea` in the background and write the output to a HTML element which can be styled.

Comment: So my approach basically cant work and i have to try something else?

Comment: Yup. Have a read of http://codemirror.net//1/story.html and then the open source [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) project itself

Answer (score 0):

This is will help you to find cursor position in textarea.

javascript:

```
var cursorPosition = $('#myTextarea').prop("selectionStart");
```

Html:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea" rows="40" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Nope, this doesnt work, it counts all the chars ive entered, not only the new lines.

Comment: @YUNOWORK can u do one thing. place the code inside the mouseenter function and check it once.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<textarea onkeyup="getLineNumber(this, document.getElementById('lineNo'));" onmouseup="this.onkeyup();"></textarea>
<div id="lineNo"></div>

<script>

function getLineNumber(textarea, indicator) {

    indicator.innerHTML = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
}

</script>
```